# Are there any projects using the Qt libraries for other things than desktop clients?

Tags: c++, qt

Qt has libraries for other things than UI:s. Are there any larger projects using the Qt libraries for other things that desktop clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt does have a home in the [embedded market space](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-embedded-linux/).  I have seen applications in many different fields, including Building Security Systems, Medical Devices, GPS Units, Car Entertainment Systems, Tablets, and even Smart Phones.  A look at the [Qt in Use Speakers and Abstracts](http://qt.nokia.com/qtdevdays2011/abstracts/) from the 2011 Qt Developers Days gives some more applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about specific projects out there which use QT, but there seems to be a lot of information about non-desktop / server QT usage.

Here's a link to a [QT example for a HTTP server](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice/examples/server) if it helps!

What are you looking for specifically?

Comment: Thanks.. it was more of a general question. It seems like the Qt library is quite massive. Almost equal to Java's standard API. Since it is cross platfom it seems like the Qt lib would be a perfect fit for most (80%+) of all C++ apps.